# Notepad++/other editors: How to view same file in multiple columns with auto scrolling?

Tags: vim, emacs, notepad++, sublime-text

Is there any editor that allows me to have two columns, where the second column picks up after the last line of the first column? I don't mean cloning like in Notepad++ where I have two open copies of the document, but a view where the same document displays in the second column from the point after the first column is full.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Emacs, there's a package to do just that called [**`follow-mode`**](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Follow-Mode.html).  You can read about it with `C-h r i follow-mode RET`.

To use Follow mode, go to a frame with just one window, split it into two side-by-side windows using C-x 3, and then type M-x follow-mode. From then on, you can edit the buffer in either of the two windows, or scroll either one; the other window follows it.

To turn off Follow mode, type M-x follow-mode a second time.

Comment: follow-mode is great! And it lets you have as many columns as you want.

Comment: How would I add more than 2 columns? I used C-x 3 M-x follow-mode.

Answer (score 2):

For Vim, there's the [MPage](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=4545) plugin by the well-known plugin author DrChip. You can specify the number of columns to the `:MPage` command.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

In Vim, you might be able to `:set scrollbind` on two windows on the same buffer after setting them up to an appropriate initial configuration. But I've found they don't always stay in sync very well as you edit and move around.